# Assigning Values to a Structures Vector

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, struct, nested

I am trying to assign values to a structure vector inside a structure
An example code is shown below

```
struct Command
{
    string channel;
    string channelDescriptor;
};

struct Frame
{
    string id;
    std::vector<Command> comm;

};
```

So I am trying to assign different commands in a single frame.

What I have right now is:

```
Frame mFrame;
mFrame.comm.push_back(Command({"testing","testing2"}));;
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? Can you describe the problems you are experiencing?

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have a question for us to answers? Your code looks good.

Comment: Do you have C++11 support?

Answer (score 1):

You can first make a Command and then add it:

```
Command comm;
comm.channel = "testing";
comm.channelDescriptor = "testing2";

Frame mFrame;
mFrame.comm.push_back(comm);
```

Even better is to make a function for this.